# sql local db is not starting - Err : because it was originally formatted with sector size 4096 and is now on a volume with sector size 3072

Tags: sql, sql-server, windows

I have encountered problem in starting the sql local db, in sql server 2008 R2. Following err

*" because it was originally formatted with sector size 4096 and is now on a volume with sector size 3072. Move the file to a volume with a sector size that is the same as or smaller than the original sector size."* , i ran the check chksdk, and it seems the allocation unit it 4096

Any help on this would be much appreciable

Comment: Did you managed to get a solution???
I have to use a software that installs sql server local db 2012 and it cannot start because of this error!